# On second navigation to sub-tab window.location is pointing to main tab url

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, parameters

I am using query parameters in the URL to pass attribute to app page sub-tab.

`let paramsURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1));`

If I open the tab first-time it open without any issue but if close the tab and reopen tab, `window.location` in sub-tab doInit points to the main tab rather than sub-tab and after full page load, it points to the sub-tab location.

Before the spring 21 update, everything was working fine but now `window.location` behaving unexpectedly.

is something changes in the recent update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In console tabs, **DONT** use window.location.

The behavior is because, when you open a subtab, the `doinit` runs before the subtab page opnes up, and as you have used window.location, the url address captures the primary tab url.

The only way to be sure to get a subtab url is [getEnclosedTabId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_getEnclosingTabId.htm) and [getTabURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_getTabURL.htm).
Enclosed tab id will return the subtab id, and that needs to be passed in getTabURL method.

Comment: is there any recent change in the behaviour because it was working till now?